# Why are you dressing so weird/weirdly?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, grammaticality

Which will you say and why:

1.Why are you dressing so weird?

2.Why are you dressing so weirdly?

A native speaker said although she knew sentence one is grammatically incorrect, she would probably say “weird” because that word is more common and therefore sounds more natural.

Comment: I have to disagree with your native speaker friend: although it's a common mistake, it certainly doesn't sound _more_ natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/so) explains that you can use **so** as a degree adverb to modify either an adjective or an adverb. While it does give examples, it doesn't explain explicitly where you should use each option.

As a general rule, you use an adjective **slow** to modify a noun, and an adverb **slowly** to modify a verb, adjective or adverb:

> This **train** is slow
> This train is **moving** slowly

In your sentence, it modifies **dressing**, which is a verb form, so you should use the adverb **wierdly**.

> Why are you **dressing** so weirdly?

Note that you would only use present continuous if they were watching somebody putting on their clothes right now, and were commenting on the particular clothes that they had chosen to wear on this occasion. If you want to comment on the kind of clothing they habitually wear, you would use present simple:

> Why do you **dress** so weirdly?

You can use the adjective **weird** if it modifies a noun, for example:

> Why are your **clothes** so weird?

The distinction between adjectives and adverbs is complicated because, in informal US English, it is common to use adjectives as adverbs. Here's a sentence with two adjectives used as adverbs- **real** modifies the adjective **good** and **good** modifies the verb **doing**.

> I'm doing real good. -*common in informal US English*
> I'm doing really well. -*correct usage*

Answer (score 1):

The grammar of your sentences was wrong.

*Why are you dressed so weirdly?* This is grammatically correct and could be said by anyone.

*Why are you dressed so weird?* This is not so correct. It can be considered a slangy way of speaking and would probably be used by someone who would criticise another person so freely!

Comment: A nitpick: "Why are you dressing so weirdly?" isn't grammatically wrong, it just has a slightly different meaning (that is admittedly, probably not the meaning the OP is looking for).

Comment: I agree with the substance of your answer, but you have not explained why one is correct and the other is not.

Comment: I am terribly sorry for the confusion. My original sentence was wrong. Thank you for pointing out. Now it’s correct.

Comment: @Ryan M - The OP changed the question after I answered.